# Trouble importing statsmodels despite system telling me it is imported

Tags: python, import, installation, pip, statsmodels

Seems this is not an uncommon issue but I am yet to resolve it and the other answers here haven't yet led me to the light.

I just cannot seem to import statsmodels (currently on mac OS X yosemite) but the issue also persists on my Windows machine.

I have tried various methods to no avail, but when I check in terminal

```
python -c "import statsmodels"
echo $?
0
```

and

```
python -c "import patsy"
echo $?
0
```

as it has been suggested several times on these posts Patsy might need to be installed first. So it seems as per the above stats models is installed in my machine, though it does not physically seem to exist in my lib path.

When I (try to) import statsmodels into the python terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm    CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named statsmodels
```

I have tried to uninstall, and reinstall, and also

```
easy_install -U statsmodels
```

In terminal which yields (after heaps of code and some warning messages)

```
Installed /Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-   packages/statsmodels-0.6.1-py3.5-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for statsmodels
Finished processing dependencies for statsmodels
```

Can anybody offer some insight into what is going here, or anything I might be missing completely/simply doing wrong?

Appreciate the comments!